# Inconsistant iBeacon detections

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, ibeacon

I am trying to detect iBeacons from a App Killed state on iOS 7.1 + devices . On certain devices (not a specific phone model) the app works without a glitch.

However on some devices the app does not detect the beacons . I have double check the settings on those devices such as location services , permissions, background app fetch , bluetooth etc.

I have enabled "notifyEntryStateOnDisplay" as well . Therefore I am testing by locking the device and turning it back on . However certain devices does detect the beacon.(The battery was full as well).

I thought  "notifyEntryStateOnDisplay" will cause to detect iBeacons everytime I turned the device on. What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` option is designed to give you an extra callback to `didDetermineState:forRegion:` when the user hits the shoulder button to turn on the display.  That callback may not happen when the phone first boots up.  In fact, my tests show that CoreLocation isn't even active for the first 60 seconds or so after the display first comes on.

A couple of things to check:

1. Make sure that your logic is inside `didDetermineState:forRegion:` and not `didEnterRegion:` or `didExitRegion:`.
2. When you boot up, wait 60 seconds before hitting the shoulder button and expecting results.

Comment: Can this kinda behaviour happen even after a boot up ?

Comment: Yes, my point is you cannot rely on an immediate detection after bootup using `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay`.  You must wait for CoreLocation to start up, which takes about an extra minute after boot.  Then hitting the shoulder button or the home button to illuminate the display should work as you desire.